# Calling two different Procedures with Transaction in another Procedure

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, transactions, procedure

this is the Flow for the Procedure

```
sp_test(in_var1, in_var2, in_var3)
begin
    if(a record exists) then
        call sp_test_update(in_var1, in_var2, in_var3)
    else
        call sp_test_insert(in_var1, in_var2, in_var3)
end

sp_test_insert(in_var1, in_var2, in_var3)
begin
    declare exit handler for sqlexception
    begin
        rollback
    end
    start transaction
        /*
            code block for insert
        */
    commit
end  

sp_test_update(in_var1, in_var2, in_var3)
begin
    declare exit handler for sqlexception
    begin
        rollback
    end
    start transaction
        /*
            code block for update
        */
    commit
end
```

Already tried making a **single** Procedure but the application has a *different process* for handling the insert and update, causing problem in stored data.

Will this kind of approach in a Procedure..

..a bad **Implementation**? or **Practice**? or **Coding**?
..make a huge effect in the **performance** of the DB Server?
..cause a **bottleneck** when being flooded by request by users?

Answer (score 0):

While that will work it is not neccessary. MySQL already has 2 methods to handle this use case:

REPLACE http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

and ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

So read about them, choose which to implement and code 1 proc with it.

Comment: Already read and tried about the said topic, getting same success result as expected. Thanks for your effort mate! Cheers

Comment: OK, that was your single proc attempt and the stored data problem. In that case I don't see how any other sp call will work either since it will be a blind call to an sp. You will have to do the test in your client code first and then call the specific sp using the specific process. Why don't you know if it is an existing entity? What framework/orm are you using?